# Getting MIME type error when deploying project online

Tags: python, reactjs, django, flask, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error when I try to load a CSS file in my Django project:

Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/index-b4422385.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I have tried to fix the problem by changing the MIME type of the file, but this has not worked.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/index-b4422385.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/js/index-580b2f9b.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my static file configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dist", "assets")),
]
```

I have already built my React app.

In my Django logs, I am receiving the following errors:

```
Not Found: /assets/css/index-b4422385.css
[06/Aug/2023 22:34:58] "GET /assets/css/index-b4422385.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3999
Not Found: /assets/js/index-580b2f9b.js
[06/Aug/2023 22:34:58] "GET /assets/js/index-580b2f9b.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3993
```

I have tried adding the following setting to my settings.py file, but this has not worked:

```
STATICFILES_MIMETYPES = {
    ".css": "text/css",
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Expected behavior:**

The CSS file should be loaded without any problems.

**Actual behavior:**

The CSS file is not loaded and I am getting the error message mentioned above.

**Possible solutions:**

- I am not sure what the problem is.
- The MIME type of the CSS file is not set correctly.
- The static file configuration is incorrect.

**Additional context:**

I am using Django 3.2.8 and Python 3.10.1.

If anyone needs more code to understand, please specify and I would be happy to share it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're loading the static files and referencing them correctly:

```html
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index-b4422385.css' %}">
```

2. Then make sure that your urls.py doesn't have any conflicts. If so, django will return `text/html` page instead of your static file.
3. Also, we're talking about DEBUG=True mode, if you set it to False and want to have a production ready solution, you must to consider setup an webserver properly to serve static and media files. Here is example for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;  # replace with your domain name

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/your/staticfiles/;  # replace with the path to your static files directory
        expires 30d;  # optional: set cache expiration for static files
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /path/to/your/mediafiles/;  # replace with the path to your media files directory
        expires 30d;  # optional: set cache expiration for media files
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;  # assuming your Django project is running on port 8000
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```